# How do I automate the process of sending the full text of my saved feedly items to Evernote?

Tags: rss, evernote, api

I use feedly as a newsreader, but prefer to do my actual reading in Evernote, so I can quickly save and label articles I want to save. I end up spending a lot of time using Evernote web clipper to export the articles one at a time.

I've tried using IFTTT to automate the process, but it only sends the summary text of saved articles.

I'd like to try and build a tool to do all this myself. I have limited programming experience (I took C in college), but I really don't even know where to start on building something like this.

How do I write a program that gets the url from the title of the feedly item, then imports the full text of that url's page to Evernote?